# Changing how the LaTeX listings package renders the tilde

Tags: latex, listings

I am working on a book which has a lot of code in the JAGS modelling language. In JAGS, the user can specify the distribution the data are supposed to have originated from, and priors for the parameters. The operator used to do this is the tilde `~`. For example

```
model{
  for(i in 1:n){
    speed[i] ~ dnorm(mu, tau)
  }

  mu ~ dnorm(0, 0.000001)
}
```

I am formatting the code in the book using the `listings` package which is pretty awesome. However, I would like the tilde character to be formatted in the same way as it is on this page - centered in the "height" of the text. This is what I get from listings

[image: JAGS code rendered using the <code>listings</code> package in LaTeX]

I am assuming there is a section for operators, but I have not been able to find one.

Comment: Hi James, I just voted to migrate your (good) question on TeX.SE: in there you will find an army of experts answering to you in no time...while here you can only rely on 9 views in 4 days... ;)

Comment: Thanks @MattAllegro - Thanks! Do I need to migrate it myself? I had actually thought that the two sites were linked these days.

Comment: You can delete and repost on TeX SE, I think this is the best (quickest) way to avoid cross-site duplicates and get a high quality answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use another font for the tilde:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        literate={~}{{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont \textasciitilde}}1
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
model{
  for(i in 1:n){
    speed[i] ~ dnorm(mu, tau)
  }

  mu ~ dnorm(0, 0.000001)
}
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain what the `1` does at the end of the `literate` line please? It seems kind of out of place

Comment: @JamesCurran The `1` stands for the length of the output, your tilde is `1` character long. For details see page 51 of the listings documentation

Comment: @JamesCurran Just for fun, you could replace the `1` by `9` and you'll see that much more space is reserved for the tilde

Comment: I get `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]` after a substantial number of occurrences of `~` in a listing.  Is there a remedy for that?

Comment: @AstroFloyd Can you ask a new question including a [mre] that allows us to reproduce the problem?